# Adding a certificate to a WCF client. Cannot find X.509 certificate

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I have a WCF client that is going to authenticate against some web service using a certificate issued by said service. At first my client used a https binding as below:

```
var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
```

but this gave the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The client certificate is not provided.
>   Specify a client certificate in ClientCredentials.

I then added the following code to my client configuration:

```
this.ChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate("test", System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My);
```

And now I get the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot find the X.509 certificate
>   using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation
>   'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectDistinguishedName', FindValue
>   'test'.'

I am absolutely certain that the certificate is placed in the Personal folder on my Local Machine, but it still cannot find it. I have tried placing the certificate in various folders, renaming it, using the thumbprint for identification, but my application still can't find it. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you set up the certificate by using `X509FindType.FindByThumbprint`.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
//client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9ee8be61d875bd6e1108c98b590386d0a489a9ca");
```

It corresponds to the below value.
[image]
In order to allow WCF service could access this local certificate, we usually add `Everyone` account to the management group of the certificate private key.
Besides, WCF service with authenticating the client with a certificate, this usually requires that we set up both the service certificate and the client certificate on the client-side.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it seems that my application can find the certificate, but now I get an error saying `Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority xyz`. Does that mean there is something wrong with the certificate or as you mention that perhaps the WCF service cannot access the private key or something like that?

Comment: Not only do we need to add the Everyone account to the private key management group of certificates (actually the account that runs the program), we also need to establish a trust relationship between the server and the client, which means that the server trusts the client's certificate and the client trusts the server's certificate.

Comment: Okay. The trust relationship should be established as I have generated a .csr file that I sent to the server and they sent the certificate back (a .p7b file) which I installed on my computer. I'm not sure how to add the Everyone account to the private key management group as I'm quite new to certificates

Comment: Right-click the certificate in the certificate store, All Tasks-> Manage Private Keys-> Add.

Comment: All tasks only gives me the options 'Request certificate with new key' and 'Renew certificate with new key'.

Comment: It should be your Client certificate. not the server certificate. one more thing, the certificate should have client authentication/server authentication intended purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202041/discussion-between-palbo-and-abraham-qian).

Comment: Been fighting a problem off and on for over a year and this solved it. Thank you!